# ms-access: clear text in all controls with one click

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

i have some comboboxes and some textboxes on a form

i would like to clear all of them with one line of code. is that possible?

something like `all_controls.text=""`

Comment: Why do you want to clear them? Is it for data entry? Do you have a recordset? If so, moving to a new record may suit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not with one line of code.  You will have to walk through all of the controls with a loop.

```
Dim ctl As Control
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If (ctl.ControlType = acTextBox) Then
        ctl.Value = Null
    End If
Next ctl
```

http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=5010

Comment: If you're doing this often, say in an unbound form that is used in a query-by-form interface, it's vastly faster to assign the controls you're clearing to a custom collection in the OnLoad event of the form, and then walk that collection instead of the entire controls collection.